# Issue with Android libraries and project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to create a android project with two libraries,however, I have been able to link the two libraries I created with my android project.
I have same xml name in two libbaries,when I am compiling my project, the R.java file is getting compiled in my new project and I am getting only one xml file from the two libraries. how could I link the two libraries in my android project with the same xml names? I know it can be done with diff names but I want the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have say strings.xml in /res/values in both library projects and expect to get more than one strings.xml in your consuming project?

From what I experience, if I have strings.xml in library projects and also in my consuming project, the resulting R.java will have the values from all 3 merged together, with any duplicate entries having the value as defined in the consuming project.

Comment: No I want to get my values from two libraries of res/layout/main.xml into my main project without being overlapped. The name of all the values in res/layout/main.xml is same.

Comment: When i am compiling the code,I am getting r.java generated with all my values overlapped.Depending on which library is declared above in the list ,only elements from that value is taken

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. That's the way library projects are designed to work. Resources are merged into the parent project. If you want values from both libraries to make it in, they need to have different resource IDs, and even then you'll have one resource file (unless you have different file names to start with).

The only way you could get this to "work" is to do something with your build process renaming the files, which is doable, but not trivial, especially if there are possible resource ID conflicts and even harder if your main project needs to use any of those resources directly.

Comment: So you saying that having same xml name in two libraries and merging them together is not possible?Its works fine for diff xml names but I need to have same xml name  for my project. IS there any way I can do that?

Comment: I'm saying it will merge them into one resource file in your main project.

Comment: Thats what its doing.Merging into one is fine  but i want both the xml with same name in my final build. IS there a way around to do it?